# Grab each forward slash as parameter with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this *.htaccess* code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/*$ ./index.php?page=$1
```

This allows one to append a paramater after the forward slash and be used as a `$_GET` in PHP like so:

URL:

```
http://www.url.com/home
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['home'];
?>
```

My question is, how do I grab each forward slash and pass that value as a new `$_GET` for PHP to use? I'm assuming the problem is going to use a regex solution, but since I'm not clued up on regex I can't figure it out.

Just to clarify by example, I want this:

```
http://www.url.com/param1/param2/param3
```

To translate to:

```
$_GET['param1'];
$_GET['param2'];
$_GET['param3'];
```

Etc., etc.

Comment: pass it as a simple single string, and then `explode()` it in PHP. It'll be far easier that way than trying to come up with a mod_rewrite that can handle an arbitrary number of parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would it help if I wanted a set number of parameters that I can change. For example: `http://www.url.com/category-name/post-alias`, which of course translates to category name and post ID or alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that inside the rewriting module.

Instead make a simple rewrite to your script and access the raw reqeust ($_SERVER['HTTP_REQUEST_URI']) in there. You get the path that was specified inside the request which you can separate at the slashes by using the explode() function.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]+)/?$   http://www.example.com/index.php?par1=$1&par2=$2&par3=$3 [L]
```

Can't use (.*) because includes the slash.

Comment: missing a 3rd `)` in there.

Comment: I understood the question such that there might occur an arbitrary number of slashes.

Comment: And... why should be look for the literal strings 'param...' ?

Comment: @Marc Thank you. Corrected. Your idea is far better, though.

Comment: $arkascha It can be anything, This is just an idea. I will modify it.